# Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. error

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, mobile

I exported mobile from unity and tried to convert it to mobile in android studio but it evolved this error

[image: error]

Comment: Why aren’t you building from the unity editor?

Comment: it gives gradle build error there too.